# System.Gadget.onSettingsClosing not working on my gadget

Tags: javascript, widget, windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to see if System.Gadget.onSettingsClosing is working,

here's my code

my.js

```
System.Gadget.settingsUI = "../Settings.html";
System.Gadget.onSettingsClosing = settingsClosing;

function settingsClosing(){

document.getElementById('banner').innerHTML = "Changed!";       

}
```

but no luck, tsk.

gadget.html

```
<div id = "banner">Not Changed</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these things in your gadget.html script:

```
System.Gadget.settingsUI = "../Settings.html";

function SettingsClosed(event){
 if(event.closeAction===event.Action.commit){
  [whatever - usually reading settings and then using them in some way]
 }
}

System.Gadget.onSettingsClosed=SettingsClosed;
```

and put these in your Settings.html script

```
function SettingsClosing(event){
 if(event.closeAction===event.Action.commit){
  [whatever- usually saving settings]
  event.cancel=false;
 }  
 else{event.cancel=true;}
}

System.Gadget.onSettingsClosing=SettingsClosing;
```

Please see:

[System.Gadget.onSettingsClosing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[System.Gadget.onSettingsClosed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)